# Randomising each time button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, random

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#create root window
root = Tk()

#variables
roll = StringVar(root, name = "roll")

#button script
def clicked():
    x = str(random.randint(1,6))
    root.setvar(name = "roll", value = x)

#button
btn = Button(root, text = "Roll!", fg = "red", bg = "#2596be",
             command = clicked(), height = 5, width = 10,
             font = buttonFontTuple)
btn.pack()

#label
lbl = Label(root, text="You rolled a " + root.getvar(name = "roll"),
            anchor="center", bg="orange", fg="#008080", font=fontTuple,
            borderwidth="1")
lbl.pack(ipadx=0, ipady=10)
```

This code creates a button and label. The button is meant to change x to a random number and then it will display in the label, however, each time I press the button nothing appears to happen. The number changes every time the code is run though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `command` argument for `Button` expects a function. When you write `clicked()` you call the function once, and command gets what your function returns (which is `None`), so when you click on the button, the command that is executed is `None`, so nothing happens.

What you want is to pass the function instead, not call it:

```py
btn = Button(root, text = "Roll!", fg = "red", bg = "#2596be",
             command = clicked, height = 5, width = 10,
             font = buttonFontTuple)
```

Since you call the function once (when the button is created), you see a number, different every time you start the code though, so that's why the code behaves this way